# How to pass function a output of select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, join

I am working on following query

```
    Select p.* from Product Inner Join Product_Category_Maping pcm on P.Id=Pcm.ProductId
    where  
dbo.[CHECKCHARINDEX](@Keyword,p.Name+' '+
     @CatName=(Select C.Name from category C where C.Id=Pcm.CategoryId))=1
```

I want to pass both product and category name to function for some check . How can I do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to move the `select` to a `join`. Makes it easier and clearer.

```
select p.*
from   product p
join   product_category_maping pcm
on     p.id = pcm.productid
join   category c
on     c.id = pcm.categoryid
where  dbo.[checkcharindex](@keyword, p.name + ' ' +  c.name) = 1
```

Also, I think you forgot to give the `product` table the alias `p`.

Comment: Yep I did forget it. Thanks for your reply. This i think is the best way, but i am in a situation where i cant decide whether to use join, b'coz my stored procedure is quite big and i dont want to add extra overload on it anymore. Still will work on it

Comment: What do you think the inner sub query does? It's also overhead.